# Creating Multidimensional Nested Array from MySQL Result with Duplicate Values (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, nested, duplicates

I currently am pulling menu data out of our database using the PDO fetchAll() function. Doing so puts each row of the query results into an array in the following structure:

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
                       [MenuId] => mmnlinlm08l6r7e8ju53n1f58 
                       [MenuName] => Main Menu 
                       [SectionId] => eq44ip4y7qqexzqd7kjsdwh5p 
                       [SubmenuName] => Salads & Appetizers
                       [ItemName] => Tomato Salad
                       [Description] => Cucumbers, peppers, scallions and cured tuna
                       [Price] => $7.00) 
        [1] => Array ( 
                       [MenuId] => mmnlinlm08l6r7e8ju53n1f58 
                       [MenuName] => Main Menu 
                       [SectionId] => xlkadsj92laada9082lkas 
                       [SubmenuName] => Entrees 
                       [ItemName] => Portabello Carpaccio
                       [Description] => Dried tomatoes, pin nuts, mahon cheese
                       [Prices] => $18.00)
 )                      
                       ...etc.
```

For parsing reasons, I would like to have the array appear in a nested structure with no duplicate values:

```
Array ( 
          [MenuName] => Main Menu
          [MenuId] => mmnlinlm08l6r7e8ju53n1f58 
          [Section] =>  Array ( 
                                [SectionId] => eq44ip4y7qqexzqd7kjsdwh5p 
                                [SubmenuName] => Salads & Appetizers
                                [Items] => Array (
                                                    [ItemName] => Tomato Salad
                                                    [Description] => Cucumbers, peppers, scallions and cured tuna
                                                    [Prices] => Array (
                                                                        [PriceId] => xksjslkajiak1
                                                                        [Price] => $7.00)
                                                  ) 

                               [SectionId] => xlkadsj92laada9082lkas
                               [SubmenuName] => Entrees
                               [Items] => Array (                           
                                                   [ItemName] => Portabello Carpaccio
                                                   [Description] => Dried tomatoes, pin nuts, mahon cheese
                                                   [Prices] => Array (
                                                                        [PriceId => alkadh29189s09
                                                                        [Price] = $8.00)
                                                  )
                               )
)
```

As a n00b programmer, I've been racking my brain for the last day trying to figure out how to create this new, multidimensional array. It seems like I may have to use a couple of nested foreach statements and references, but I've had a hard time getting anything to work.

Does anyone know how I can go about doing so?

Comment: is your data strictly hierarchical?  In other words Items are always grouped in a submenu and submenus are grouped in a section, and sections are grouped in a menu?

If so, in your SQL query, sort by those (menu, section, submenu), then as you iterate through your results, check to see that each level has not changed and add your array.

Comment: Hi Aerik, yes, each item is always grouped into a submenu and each submenu is grouped into a menu. My SQL results currently are ordered in this manner, so all items in Main Menu > Appetizers are grouped together, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like what you are looking for

```
$array = array() ;

while ($row = PDO::fetchAll()) // Replace with relevant Information
{
    $section = array();
    $items  = array();
    $prices  = array();

    if(!array_key_exists($row['MenuId'], $array))
    {
        $array[$row['MenuId']] = array();
        $array[$row['MenuId']]['MenuName'] = $row['MenuName'] ;
        $array[$row['MenuId']]['MenuId'] = $row['MenuId'] ;
        $array[$row['MenuId']]['Section'] = array();
    }

    if(!array_key_exists($row['SectionId'], $array[$row['MenuId']]['Section']))
    {
        $array[$row['MenuId']]['Section'][$row['SectionId']] = array();
        $array[$row['MenuId']]['Section'][$row['SectionId']]['SectionId'] = $row['SectionId'] ;
        $array[$row['MenuId']]['Section'][$row['SectionId']]['SubmenuName'] = $row['SubmenuName'] ; 
        $array[$row['MenuId']]['Section'][$row['SectionId']]['Items'] = array() ;

    }

    $items['ItemName'] = $row['ItemName'] ;
    $items['Description'] = $row['Description'] ;

    $prices['PriceId']  = $row['PriceId'] ;
    $prices['Price']  = $row['Price'] ;

    $items['Prices'] = $prices ;
    $section['Items'] = $items ;

    $array[$row['MenuId']]['Section'][$row['SectionId']]['Items'][] = $items ;

}


var_dump($array);
```

With just minor changes you can make it what you want

Comment: Thanks for that baba. It looks like your solution presents a significant drain on resources ("Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded").

Comment: @idubs11 i was working with limited resources .... not sure of the size of data you where dealing with ... what you want to use the format for .. if you give more detailed information i think i can help improve the answer

Comment: Typical queries result in about 50-150 rows. The formatted data is then going to be parsed and presented in the phtml.

Comment: Can i have data in `.sql`format .. i would write a very optimized script based on the data and the format you have specified above then update my answer

Comment: sure! I've uploaded the data to: http://www.2shared.com/document/-i2i883o/Menus.html

Comment: @idubs11 - I ran Baba's solution with the dataset that you posted and it executed in 0.0027s. Maybe there is a problem in your view file.

Comment: @Baba I believe the file should be available since nnichols could access it.

Comment: @nnichols, thanks for that, I'll check the view file to make sure.

Comment: @nnichols I just ran it again and I'm getting the following error: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted. The error line points to the 'while' statement. Might this have to do with the nature of FetchAll()?

Comment: Are you using native PDO? Try using `while ($row = $db->fetch())` where $db is the handle to the prepared statement/executed query.