# Remove duplicate values from a multidimensional array based on a specific key

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

Got a multidimensional array like this one:

```
[['key'=>'foo', 'Rating'=>5] ,  
 ['key'=>'bar', 'Rating'=>1] ,
 ['key'=>'Tee', 'Rating'=>3] ,
 ['key'=>'foo', 'Rating'=>10] ,
 ['key'=>'foo', 'Rating'=>1]]
```

I want to remove duplicates based on a specific key and a Rating system while maintaining the original array structure except index keys.

So the final result should look like this:

```
[['key'=>'bar', 'Rating'=>1] ,
 ['key'=>'Tee', 'Rating'=>3] ,
 ['key'=>'foo', 'Rating'=>10]]
```

I'm looking for an efficient solution to this problem.

Ideally an `array_unique()` function that accepts a key value as a parameter to find repetitions on a given array and the `Rating` key.

```
array_key_unique($array, $uniqe_key, $Rating);
```

I was wondering if there is any way to do this with MySQL query?

Comment: how you come to know that `['key'=>'foo', 'Rating'=>5] ,` is a duplicate and need to remove. look at your desired output and tell

Comment: you should also post the part where you fetch the data from MySQL and also post table structure with data because your question is marked as MySQL.... the best solution would be the let the database handle the grouping and max values something like this... SELECT 
   Rates.`key`
 , MAX(Rates.Rating)
FROM 
 Rates
GROUP BY
 Rates.`key`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Multidimensional Nested Array from MySQL Result with Duplicate Values (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049175/creating-multidimensional-nested-array-from-mysql-result-with-duplicate-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Raymond Nijland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2548147/raymond-nijland) states in the comments, better to do it in the query:

```
SELECT `key`, MAX(`Rating`) FROM `table_name` GROUP BY `key`
```

But because I was bored, loop and add the one with highest `Rating` to the result:

```
foreach($array as $value) {
    if(!isset($result[$value['key']]) || $result[$value['key']]['Rating'] < $value['Rating']) {
        $result[$value['key']] = $value;
    }
}
```

Or, sort ASCending and extract an array with `key` as the index to overwrite duplicates:

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'key'),
                array_column($array, 'Rating'),
                SORT_ASC, $array);

$result = array_column($array, null, 'key');
```

In either case, to re-index to an integer based array, use:

```
$result = array_values($result);
```